# Does an object hovering in the atmosphere rotate with the earth?

Tags: forces

Suppose an object comes from space and is put some kilometers away from the earth's surface (where there is low density of air).Will it rotate with the earth?

Now, suppose a helicopter lift off the earth and accelerates until imitates the behaviour of the space object (so there is now implications of the principle of inetia).

I think this idea would imply *to travel faster or to use much less energy*. Is that right?

Comment: a hovering helicopter with no air - wtf ;)

Comment: I do not know how to say it, but the problem is clear, isn't it?

Comment: no, actually my comment was not just humorous :) the air is not moving with respect to the ground (it sometimes does, but the energy is consumed by friction pretty fast; and wind velocities are negligible compared to the earth rotation) - so there is no way to neglect air resistance if you want to move with respect to the earth. Just no way.

Comment: I think density of air is very small some kilometers away

Comment: Yes, that's why airplanes fly so high. But it has nothing to do with earth's movement. They just don't care, that earth is moving or rotating. I assume, you wanted to use an object that comes from outside the earth (it doesn't have to be a helicopter, take some asteroid, they are more common out there) and use its movement to travel with respect to earth. This might work (theoretically, not in practice). But you cannot reuse the object, it will travel on after you disembark. To get it back, you need to put in energy, which you wanted to avoid.

Comment: i reposted it as an answer and hope to have understood your thoughts more or less correctly

Comment: That is why I asked of the question was clear. ;).Yes but maybe the energy used will be less.

Comment: Moreover, physicist do a lot a problems like  this (what car has no friction?) so, helicopter or asteroid is the same and there is no air as o said.

Answer (score 1):

No. The helicopter will not move with respect to the ground if it is hovering. It will remain in the same spot. It is moving WITH the rotation of the earth and earth's atmosphere.

Comment: then, technically, after 24h it would be in its initial position :-P

Comment: but what is the force which move the helicopter?

Comment: The force of friction has accelerated the helicopter (and everything on  the surface of the earth for that matter) to that of the rotation of the earth. Everything we make or interact with has already been accelerated to this speed upon the formation of the planet so it is imperceptible to us.

Comment: friction with the air? And why air moves with the earth?

Comment: The friction could be with the air or the ground. Typically it's with the ground. All the parts to build the helicopter came from the ground. Which is already rotating with the earth and continues to do so as you move the material around on the surface. Since the air is also already moving with the earth it doesn't contribute any extra force once the helicopter is up in the air.  It's the same thing as if you jumped straight up. You and all the air around you is still moving with the surface of the earth at the same constant speed and there is nothing opposing this motion.

Comment: The air moves with the earth because it is gravitationally bound. The short answer is: angular momentum conservation.

Comment: Gravity acts in that direction? What do you mean with gravitationally bound? And what if the helicopter has an opposite (but equal in magnitude) velocity respect to the earth, and there is no air? Would it moves with the earth? Sorry, but you are not clearing my doubts

Comment: IF you give the helicopter velocity then obviously it moves with respect to the earth. That's what velocity is. Speed relative to another object. Typically we use the earth as the main object of comparison.  I'm struggling to come up with another way to explain it. Think of it like you are sitting on a moving train holding a baseball. If the train is moving 50km/h (relative to earth) how fast is the ball moving? 50km/h. Now throw the ball straight up in the air a few feet. How fast is the ball moving now? Still 50km/h in the horizontal direction. You are bound to the train and the ball to you.

Comment: @santimirandarp Consider what would happen if the atmosphere did not move with the rotation of the Earth: at the equator the relative speeds would be about $460\,\mathrm{m/s}$, which is comfortably supersonic.  Frictional forces from wind would rapidly dump angular momentum from the planet into the atmosphere at the surface, and turbulent mixing within the atmosphere would propagate this, until it was (approximately) co-rotating with the planet.  It would be entertaining to set up an atmospheric simulation to model this: I expect they do not deal well with supersonic winds though.

Comment: @BradS Actually no (if we ignore frame-dragging which is safe here): the atmosphere moves with the Earth's rotation (which I think is the question here) because of friction.  An atmosphere which was merely gravitationally bound would not need to exchange angular momentum with the planet.  Obviously this depends on the interpretation of 'moves with the Earth' though.

Comment: @tfb Right, which is my original answer but since he/she wasn't fully understanding I was trying to bring into the picture the formation of planet itself and the role gravity and angular momentum play in the initiation of the rotation of the planet body.

Comment: I changed the question because your answer was no te clear for me, maybe because of the question. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you want to use an object that comes from outside the earth (it doesn't have to be a helicopter, take some asteroid, they are more common out there) and use its movement to travel with respect to earth?

This might work (theoretically). But you cannot reuse the object, it will travel on after you disembark. To get it back, you need to put in energy, which you wanted to avoid.

If you wanted to build a helicopter for this purpose, then ask yourself: how does it get there (in front of the earth and with no initial velocity). You will need the same energy to prepare it which you save afterwards.

Well, and in practice... ;) catching asteroids is quite a hard task; it could be easier to build a great windmill working on incoming asteroids :) a funny idea, maybe the energy source of the future.

Comment: Does a helicopter move with the rotation of the earth if it is some kilometers (or at a low density distance) from earth? Why? I think this is not an answer

Comment: If it came from outside, it will move on. If it started from earth, it will remain (nearly) above the same spot. Why? Well, why not, because it initially has the velocity of rotation already. The same reason why we can remain where we are. What is the difference between sitting in front of your computer and hovering? There is no force on you when you are sitting either.

Comment: If i say it came from space, it is because I understand inertia. You do not answer why this wouldn't be a good idea to spend less energy.

Comment: If it came from space, you have to had put it there (and give it a velocity with respect to earth) before; this energy counts, too. 
Let's make a break for today, me at least; maybe you will see it differently too if you sleep over it :)